# find elements with x:Name in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

I know how to find elements with its name, like a textblock or so:

```
TextBlock tx = my_grid.FindName(tx_string_name) as TextBox;
```

But I have an element in which the name is declared as x:Name. And I can't use the previous method or, at least, I am getting a null instance.

Is there a way to do it? it is a flyout timepicker and it doesn't seem to have name property without x.

I add more information.

I have this element:

```
TimePickerFlyout timepickerFlyout = new TimePickerFlyout();
```

And I add its name like this:

```
timepickerFlyout.SetValue(FrameworkElement.NameProperty, "Alarm_flyout_time" + value); //Value comes from a for loop
```

I added 3 or 4 and I want to access each one of them in any moment so I have to identify them.

But, when I want to access to any of them, I don't know how to look for them.

This is how I created the timepickerflyout:

```
        tb.Text = hour;
        TimePickerFlyout timepickerFlyout = new TimePickerFlyout();
        timepickerFlyout.ClockIdentifier = "24HourClock";
        timepickerFlyout.SetValue(FrameworkElement.NameProperty, "Alarm_flyout_time" + pos);
        timepickerFlyout.Closed += TimepickerFlyout_Closed;
        FlyoutBase.SetAttachedFlyout(tb, timepickerFlyout);
```

It is inside a for loop in which "pos" is the counter.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `x:Name`. Examples?

Comment: something declared like this: timepickerFlyout.SetValue(FrameworkElement.NameProperty, "Alarm_flyout_time" + pos);

Comment: This is not a declaration, also I don't know what timepickerFlyout is :( Could you give me a precise example of what you're looking for?

Comment: please, check my update.

Comment: Have you tried keeping `"Alarm_flyout_time" + value` in a list of names(strings) and looking for those?

Comment: How do I have to look for it? I tried with parent.findName("Alarm_flyout_time"+value) and it doesn't work, it returns null but the element exists

Comment: Try keeping the name that you created `string nameToLookFor = "Alarm_flyout_time"+value;` and then `findName(nameToLookFor);`

Comment: I tried too. It is not a problem of keeping the name in a string I think. Other components which names added like: component.Name = "XXX" works like a charm with findName function but not ones added with SetValue. I guess there must be another way to find that kind of components

Answer (score 0):

you cannot set the name of this flyout because a `TimePickerFlyout` is not a `FrameworkElement` and the Name property is a property from `FrameworkElement`

For example a `Button` is a control inheriting from `FrameworkElement` and then you can set it's name this way:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.Name = "buttonName";
```

Comment: I am giving a FrameworkElement.NameProperty value to a timepickerflyout and I am using it later to get its name. But I don't know how to get the Timepickerflyout instance from it.

Comment: I have the TimePickerFlyout inside a textbox. Is it possible to access to that timepickerflyout from the textbox? I can access to the textbox instance. But I don't see a child element on its properties

Comment: can you show me how you've added the flyout to the textbox?

Comment: I added to my question

Comment: I solved by adding a List. So I can keep track of all my timepickerflyouts and update their name when I have to